# Can I use more than one column in subquery?

Tags: sql, subquery

I want to show the names of all employees from the `EMPLOYEES` table who are working on more than three projects from the `PROJECT` table.

`PROJECTS.PersonID` is a a foreign key referencing `EMPLOYEES.ID`:

```
SELECT NAME, ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE ID IN
    ( 
    SELECT PersonID, COUNT(*)
    FROM PROJECTS
    GROUP BY PersonID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
    )
```

Can I have both `PersonID`, `COUNT(*)` in that subquery, or there must be only one column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in an `IN` clause (or at least not the way you are trying to use it. Some RDBMSs allow tuples with more than one column in the `IN` clause but it wouldn't help your case here)

You just need to remove the `COUNT(*)` from the `SELECT` list to achieve your desired result.

```
SELECT NAME, ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE ID IN
    ( 
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM PROJECTS
    GROUP BY PersonID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
    )
```

If you wanted to also return the count you could join onto a derived table or common table expression with more than one column though.

```
SELECT E.NAME,
       E.ID,
       P.Cnt
FROM   EMPLOYEES E
       JOIN (SELECT PersonID,
                    Count(*) AS Cnt
             FROM   PROJECTS
             GROUP  BY PersonID
             HAVING Count(*) > 3) P
         ON E.ID = P.PersonID
```

Comment: Makes sense! Huh, i thought that i had to include all the stuff that i used in Group By/Having in Select as well :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can only have 1 column for the IN subquery. You could get your results using the query below:

```
SELECT e.ID
      ,e.Name 
FROM dbo.Projects p
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Employees e
    ON p.PersonID = e.ID
GROUP BY e.ID
        ,e.Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that is probably better solution! I am learning SQL for my college exam and for some reason i really prefer subqueries instead of joins :)

Comment: Why a `LEFT` join and not `INNER`?

Comment: Out of habit when gathering sample data..., the INNER JOIN would probably net you a more optimized query plan.